# Postgres failing to start on Windows Server 2016 in Azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, localhost, virtual-machine

I am having issues starting Postgres 9.6.6 on Windows Server 2016 on an Azure VM.

When I try to start Postgres it generates a log file with the following:

```
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Permission denied
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Permission denied
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Its a completely brand new VM, I've amended postgresql.conf and the listen_addresses to include 127.0.0.1 but I still get the same binding errors.

If I run nslookup on the VM I receive back the following;

```
Server: Unknown
Address:  148.43.119.15
*** UnKnown can't find localhost: Non-existent domain
```

So I think  the fact that lookup is failing for localhost is possibly causing the problem. I've amended the hosts file on the VM to have:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
:1             localhost
```

But the same errors are occurring, so I think its something that I've not setup in terms of networking but not sure where to look.

Comment: please share postgreqls.conf for `listen_addresses` and `unix_socket_directories`

Comment: listen_addresses = '127.0.0.1,localhost,148.43.119.15' 

The  unix socket directories is blank and commented out.   #unix_socket_directories = ''

Comment: Which usser it is running the postgrees process ? this users must have permissions to bind and lsiten in these ports.

Comment: The user running the process is a member of the Windows Administrators group.

Comment: @DevOverflow When you stop postgresql `net stop postgresql-x64-9.6`, then execute `netstat -atn|findstr 5432` what is the result, port 5432 is listening?

Comment: @DevOverflow But based on my experience, you could listen service on a public IP(not bind on this VM). You could bind `*`, `localhost`, `VM private IP(like 10.0.0.4)`.

Comment: @DevOverflow Hi, does it work now?

Comment: Its still failing. I have listen_addresses as * in PostgreSQL.conf. When I stop the PostgreSQL service and execute netstat-atn|findstr 5432 nothing is listening. When I start it again and execute the same command it displays the following; TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       InHost
TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING       InHost

Comment: According to the result of `netstat -ant|findstr 5432`, postgresql is listening. Do you check you could access the service inside the VM?

Comment: I install postgresql in my Windows Server 2016 and use the default configuration, it works fine for me. Do you change other configuration? If possible, could you show you full postgreqls.conf. Maybe you could save it to github and give a link for you to check it.

Comment: `listen_addresses = '*'`  what error log return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is right, `148.43.119.15` is your VM's public IP. You could not listen postgresql on the IP, I get the same result if I set similar with you.

[image]

Please modify `postgreqls.conf`

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

For Azure VM, if you want to access postgresql with Public IP you need open port 
on Azure NSG and Windows Firewall.

[image]